# Title is not showing on the front end - Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have this component 'PostTitle' that gets the page title and changes as you edit the main page title that works in the editor, but i can't get it to show on the front end? not sure what i am doing wrong.

UPDATE

I have added a function to update the 'title' attribute, but the problem is it only fires on edit. So if you don't click on the component in the editor it won't update the 'title' attribute. Is there anyway of putting this into the save area?

```
registerBlockType( 'gutenberg/title', {
    title: 'updating text',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'h1',
        },
    },

    edit( { attributes } ) {

        const { title } = attributes;
        const GetTitle = props => props.title;
    //I'm not sure how to get this to update the title attribute
        const selectTitle = withSelect(select => ({
            title: select("core/editor").getDocumentTitle(),
         }));
        const PostTitle = selectTitle(GetTitle);

       //update function that fire when you edit the component 
       function updateTitle() {
            const pagetitle = select("core/editor").getDocumentTitle();
            setAttributes( { title: pagetitle } );
            console.log(pagetitle);
        }
        updateTitle();

        const controls = (
            <Fragment>
                 .....
            </Fragment>
        );

        return (
            <Fragment>
                { controls }        
                <PostTitle/>
            </Fragment>
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {
        const { title } = attributes;
        return (
            <div>
                <RichText.Content tagName="h1" className="title" value={ title } />
            </div>
        );
    },

} );
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: is it meant to be `gutenberg/tile` or `gutenberg/title`?

Comment: @Stender updated :)